# SQL Server resource governor classifier function

Tags: sql-server

I am in the process of creating a RG classifier function. I have already implemented this in a system where in I validate incoming sessions against only 1 login.
Now I am planning to implement below function in a different instance where in I am validating 8 users **IF ( SUSER_SNAME() in ('user1','user2','user3','user4','user5','user6','user7',user8'))**

Based on what I see in documentation, **The client session may time out if the classification function does not complete within the specified time-out for the login.**

I know this is not a complex function, still wanted to know if including multiple logins is a best practice and validating concurrent sessions from 8 application users does not cause any timeout for incoming sessions or impact

```
USE master;
GO
 
CREATE FUNCTION RGClass_funct() RETURNS SYSNAME WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @workload_group sysname;
 
  IF ( SUSER_SNAME() in ('user1','user2','user3','user4','user5','user6','user7','user8'))
      SET @workload_group = 'noncriticalServiceWG';
       
  RETURN @workload_group;
END;
GO
```

Thanks